# Can I refactor to avoid "self::" and "parent::"?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I want to extract `//pre` and `//code` elements but exclude `//pre/code`. For example:

```
<root>
    <pre><code>foo</code></pre>
    <code>bar</code>
    <pre>baz</pre>
    <span>ignore me<code>select me</code></span>
</root>
```

I want to retrieve four elements:

1. `<pre><code>foo</code></pre>`
2. `<code>bar</code>`
3. `<pre>baz</pre>`
4. `<code>select me</code>`

(And I specifically don't want `<code>foo</code>`)

The following xpath seems to do the trick:

```
//*[(self::pre or self::code) and not (self::code and parent::pre)]
```

I don't know if that's the right approach, but it seems to work.

Is there a less verbose way to express this (e.g. that doesn't require `self::` and `parent::`)?

Comment: Isn't `//*[(self::pre or self::code)` the same as `(//pre union //code)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to eliminate `self::` and `parent::` isn't really a laudable goal in general.  You may be searching for an abbreviation of those axes in the hope that they'll allow a shortened equivalent form of expression.

This is understandable given, for example, that the child axis,

```
/child::a/child:b
```

can be more concisely written

```
/a/b
```

What are the parallel abbreviations for `self::` and `parent::`?

- `self::node()` can be abbreviated `.`
- `parent::node()` can be abbreviated `..`

However, these are more useful in cases where the name of the context node or its parent are immaterial — not so in your case.  (For example, `./` is used for a relative path as opposed to `/` for an absolute path; `../@attr` is used to refer to the `attr` attribute of the parent element as opposed to `@attr` for the context element.)

So, in short, other than logical simplification as [suggested by @JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35992396/290085), your XPaths are reasonably simple already.  Axes abbreviations aren't going to be of much help.

Comment: Answer updated to reflect (I hope) a better understanding of the essence of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've helped me understand much more clearly what my XPath expression actually means.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there seems like a fine reason to use `self::` and `pre::`. I don't think there's a better way to express it without them.

Note, however, that your condition has more operands than it needs. You could express the same thing like this:

```
//*[self::pre or (self::code and not(parent::pre))]
```